# Pre-pending / Appending pairs of strings in a list

Tags: java

I have a list of pairs of strings such as:

```
A C
B D
B C
A D
```

I would like to loop through the list so that I will get a string as follows:

```
A C B D A
```

Is such a thing possible and practical if I were to have n pairs?

UPDATE: My bad for not describing it clearly.
I have a:
List x = ....
x.add("AC");
x.add("BD");
x.add("BC");
x.add("AD");
...
...

I would like to loop through such that if the next row's starting item is the current row's ending item then I will discard both and insert a new item.  Vice versa if the next row's ending item is the current row's starting item.

e.g.

Current Item: AC
Next row's item: BD

Current Item: AC
Next row's item: BC
New item: ACB

Update list will then have:

ACB
BD
AD

Then I will have to repeat the process until I get ACBDA.

Haha... talking about this already gave me an idea how to solve it.  Looks like it helps talking about it.

Comment: I guess we first have to solve the problem "What are the rules by which you obtian the desired string", and then answer how to achieve it..

Comment: Please paste your code in.  If you have a List<String> it's quite different than a List<SomePairOf<String>>

Comment: a question with a close vote and a favourite mark :)

Comment: You still didn't describe it clearly.  Your example that collapses `{AC, BC}` into `{ABC}` doesn't fit either option: both rows' ending items are the same.

Answer (score 1):

As a wild guess, what you're looking for is called a [Hamiltonian Path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path).  There should be plenty of example implementations of a Hamiltonian path solver available on the web.

Comment: This is what it looked like to me also.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a rule too, but maybe, your main problem is fetching the Strings from your datastructure and assembling them to one result string. Here's a basic aproach for that kind of task:

```
List<String[]> input = getInputFromSomewhere();
StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (String[] pairOfStrings:input) {
  resultBuilder.append(pairOfStrings[0]).append(" ");        
  resultBuilder.append(pairOfStrings[1]).append(" ");
}
String result = resultBuilder.trim();
```

Note 1 - this code *will* crash, if any of the arrays is `null` or has less then 2 items.

Note 2 - this code will *not* produce the sequence from your question.